# Html <hr> tag strange displaying

Tags: html, css, asp.net

Why is the `<hr/>` tag displaying so strange? How to fix it?

[image]

HomeController:

```
namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Department> department = new List<Department>();
        department.Add(new Department { Computers = new List<Computer> { new Computer { ID = 1 }, new Computer { ID = 2 } }, Employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee { Number = 1, Text = "Jhon" }, new Employee { Number = 2, Text = "Conorrrrrrrrrrrr" }, new Employee { Number = 3, Text = "Nick" } } });
        department.Add(new Department { Computers = new List<Computer> { new Computer { ID = 1 }, new Computer { ID = 2 }, new Computer { ID = 3} }, Employees = new List<Employee> { new Employee { Number = 1, Text = "David" } } });
        return View(new IndexViewModel { Department = department });
    }
}
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Department> Department { get; set; }

}

public class Department
{
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Computer> Computers { get; set; }
}

public class Computer
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
public class Employee
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int Number { get; set; }
}
}
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model MvcApplication4.Controllers.IndexViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@foreach(var department in Model.Department)
{
<table style="float:left;">
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var computer in department.Computers)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @computer.ID
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var employee in department.Employees)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @employee.Text
                </td>
                <td>
                    @employee.Number
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<hr />
}
```

Comment: @MrLister, Why <hr/> tag on screen displaying opposit  number "3" not. How to make displaying below "3".

Comment: @MrLister, i tried  <hr style="float:none;"/> but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should clear the float. Otherwise if the hr is directly after a floating table, it will be displayed to its right.

```html
<hr style="clear:left" />
```

Or, preferably, put

```css
hr {clear:left;}
```

in your stylesheet.